# Can't use StreamUtils in monodevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I'm trying to decompress a file... So I used SharpZipLib..
I'm using these libraries:

```
    using System;
    using Gtk;
    using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;
    using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
    using System.IO;
```

And for decompression:

```
using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullZipToPath)) {
                StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, streamWriter, buffer);
            }
```

but I get this error:

```
the name StreamUtils doesn't exist in the current context
```

What library am I missing?

Comment: where did you exact this snippet from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same issue.. couldn't solve it using streaming but while checking existed method I've found a very interesting one which is CreateZip method, which allows you to create zip compressed files..
You have to specify the destination folder and the source folder to use the method

Answer (score -1):

You're using an OLD version of ICSharpCodeLib